# Laravel 5 - SQLSTATE[22P02] - invalid text representation with postgres

Tags: php, postgresql, laravel, syntax, integer

Error:

> SQLSTATE[22P02]: Invalid text representation: 7 ERROR: invalid input
>   syntax for integer: "dismissnotification" (SQL: select * from "users"
>   where "id" = dismissnotification)

In my routes.php file:

```
Route::get('user/dismissnotification/{notificationid}',array('as' => 'dismissnotification', 'uses' => 'NotificationController@dismiss'));
```

The link with the route on my view:

```
 <a href="{{ URL::route('dismissnotification',$notification->id)}}">  <i class="fa fa-times"></i> </a>
```

When I click on this link the page is redirected correctly to (for example): 
http://mywebsite/user/dismissnotification/222222225

And the function "dismiss" on my NotificationController is empty, but the error persists. I have no idea where the `select * from "users"` in the original error comes from.

```
public function dismiss($notificationid) {
        //
}
```

Am I missing something obvious? What might be causing this error if there is no code at all in my function and the route is apparently correct?

Comment: This is a SQL problem. You have a query where a parameter has an invalid text representation. Can you trace what the query is and what the parameters are ?

Comment: for me i deployed my app in two hots with postgres, code works fine in one but not in the other, weird, and no problem with mysql in local, any news  ?

Answer (score 2):

The SQL query shows that Laravel is calling a different controller method on your route than you are expecting.

```
select * from "users" where "id" = dismissnotification
```

That query is trying to find a user with the ID matching 'dismissnotification', so it looks like it's hitting something like UsersController@show or UsersController@edit or maybe even UsersController@222222225 depending on what other routes you have defined for /user.

Since URL::route() rendered the path as you expected, your issue is probably the order in which you defined your routes; however, without seeing all of your /user routes and in the order you defined them, I can not be more specific.

Comment: In my case, it was because I had a Model relation on something other than the tables id. My fix (from @Trip hint) was to change: `$this->belongsTo( Monitor::class, 'domain' );` to instead be: `return $this->belongsTo( Monitor::class, 'domain', 'domain' );`, specifying the foreign `other` relation as well.